# Mod/preventative maintenance tip to avoid possible future death wobble in 2017 F 450?

Tags: ford, tires, steering, death-wobble

Just heard about the "[death wobble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_wobble)," and I just thought to ask this community if anyone has had some seasoned experience with avoiding it in the long term with some discovered modification(s) or preventative maintenance. This question isn't like "[Questions About the "Death Wobble"](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/questions-about-the-death-wobble)," as I am asking about mods/preventative maintenance specifically.

Comment: Thanks to SolarMike's contribution, I've located the following video that shows the difference after installing bilateral dampers: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmP8kefje6w&t=6m12s I don't know that they're actually called bilateral dampers, but the term fits, and there is a single hydraulic model. Not sure which is better. Also, as far as preventative maintenance read [here](http://www.trucktrend.com/how-to/chassis-suspension/1305dp-curring-death-wobble-tightening-up-your-steering/), or [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/75501c46d47d184de8acaa8dff5f8089) if you don't want ads.

Comment: I'd be surprised if a steering damper isn't already fitted. Don't really see that many 450s though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On some vehicles a damper (shock absorber) can be fitted to the steering linkage - it was optional or standard on Landrovers depending on the model.
[image]
Two images:

[image]

Comment: Will look into it. I [reverse image searched](http://www.series123.com/UKhomepages/index98/) to find the original discussion.

Comment: I didn’t find that discussion - relevant though it is, google was my friend for images and experience of owning and driving landrovers and fitting that type of damper...

Comment: I don’t suggest where you should purchase items : I kmow where I would go but you probably don’t have the same suppliers...